# How Would I Write 多为和平 Vertically?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, word-order

I used Google translate to tell me how to say **Mostly Peaceful** in Chinese which it said was
多为和平. I do not know any Chinese at all and I am designing a shirt where I would like to stack the words
多为和平 vertically in Chinese instead of horizontally. I want to make sure I stack the words correctly so it reads Mostly Peaceful from top to bottom. What order would the letters go in vertically?

Comment: 多为和平 doesn't make much sense in Chinese. – monalisa 15 mins ago

Comment: @monalisa Yeah, I alluded to that in my answer but it's a bit 答非所问 - the question doesn't really ask if the translation is good or not but I prompted OP to find a better translation first.

Comment: @Mou某 Yes I understand that. That's why I put this comment under the OP's question, not your answer. Your answer is perfectly fine. I just wanted to spell it out for the OP.

Comment: @monalisa Oh, my bad, I think it came up under my answer first, I got a bit confused.

Comment: Step 1: Get a better translation. Got it. Thank you all.

Comment: Sorry, my problem. Actually I did put it under your answer at first, but caught it right away (1 min, probably) and deleted it. Didn't realize you were also at the same question at the same time. :)

Comment: @monalisa I think it's the app - I had a popup on my device and when I came to the site I saw the same comment even though you had already moved it.

Answer (score 4):

Horizontal to vertical is pretty simple in modern Chinese. Vertical Chinese is read from the top down - so the first one goes at the top and then the rest follow one by one.

多为和平 would be written:

> 多
> 为
> 和
> 平

But you might want to ask for a better translation before you go and make those shirts.